# Creating a list of class instances

Tags: python, oop

I'm trying to make a simple library system as part of an intro to OOP in Python. I became stuck trying to fit books into my library class. I have made a first simple class, called Book, which makes books, can show their ID, name and price etc.

Now im trying to create the actual class called Library. I want to make a list of all the books in the library with their ID, cost and name. Here I encountered an isseu. I have no idea how to add the instances of the class Book to the list I made in Library, my code can be found down here.

```
class Library(object):

    def __init__(self, book):
        self.book = book

    def add_item(self, book):
        mylist.append(book)
        return mylist


if __name__ == '__main__':
    booklist = []
    Book1 = Book(1, 'Bookname1', "$30")
    Book2 = Book(2, 'Bookname2', "$10")
    Book1.show()
    Book1.get_attribute_string()
```

and the code for the books, which I would rather keep the same. Ofcourse im open to suggestions, but im not that well versed in OOP in Python yet so don't suggest things to complicated! Thanks.

```
class Book(object):

    def __init__(self, ID, name, price):
        self.ID = ID
        self.name = name
        self.price = price

    def show(self):
        print(self.ID, self.name, self.price)

    def get_attribute_string(self):
        print(str(self.ID) + '_' + str(self.name) + '_' + str(self.price))

    def get_id(self):
        print(self.ID)

    def get_name(self):
        print(self.name)

    def get_price(self):
        print(self.price)
```

Comment: `mylist` should be `self.mylist` and you need to add `self.mylist = []` in `__init__()`. Otherwise looks fine.

Comment: Yeah, you need to do `self.mylist.append(book)`

Comment: also you don't need to pass `book` to the __init__ function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class `Library` needs an attribute e.g. `books`. In this list, all books are stored. You need to define it in the `__init__`method, so you can have multiple libraries with different books.

```
class Library:
    def __init__():
        self.books = []

    def add_book(book):
        self.books.append(book)

    def get_books(self):
        return self.books

    def show_books(self):
        # This is one possible example how you can print all books
        for book in self.books:
            print(str(book))

class Book:
    pass # Your Book code

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}, {self.id}, {self.price}"  
        # Returns a string with all attributes of the string. 
        # Note that is a f-string, but you can use any string
        # This function is called, when you call str(book1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    book1 = Book()
    book2 = Book()
    lib = Library()
    lib.add_book(book1)
    lib.add_book(book2)
    lib.show_books()
    all_books = lib.get_books()
    also_all_books = lib.books
```

Comment: How do you show a library in this piece of code? What do you return to get the books inside a library?

Comment: I have updated to show some possible answers. Do you need any explanation for one of my changes or any other part?

Comment: I figured it out myself just now! Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your library class should probably contain a collection of books (or something more specific, depends on the details of your task). Here is an example:

```
class Library(object):

    def __init__(self, book):
        # collection of library books. This is the library state
        self.books = tuple()

    def add_item(self, book):
        # add an item to the collection
        self.books += (book, )
        return self.books
```

I preferred to use an immutable collection so that others can't change the library state outside the class. But you can use a list. You just have to be careful.

Comment: Another option to "hide" it from outside, is to prepend an underscore: `_books`. This shows developers, that this should be private.

Comment: Another option to what? Because even if I hide the *name*, `return self.books` will be a problem. Would have to be `return list(self.books)` or better yet `return tuple(self.books)`... Using immutable collections by default is best IMO. But whatever works is valid :)